# Software Upgrade causes language change in Login screen and shutdown popup window

Tags: upgrade, language, login-screen

I am running MacOS 10.13.6. I upgrade `Security Update 2018-003`, `Command line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode`, `Safari` to the latest version one day ago. The weird thing is even if the system still shows English in most parts, but the Login Screen and shutdown popup window display Chinese now. I checked **System Preferences** > **Language & Region** > I have only `English` listed in **Prefered languages** *(The region is `China` because I am currently in China)*. Can anyone please let me know how to change login screen and shutdown popup window back to show English? Thanks a lot.

Comment: why is the region set to China ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 thanks a lot for the quick reply. Because I am in China now. I need to connect to China's app store, use china timezone, show Chinese currency and among other things. The region was China before software upgrade and everything was fine. Cheers.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I thought I have expressed clearly in the question... Let's repeat what I posted in the question. Not sure if this will help or not. `Security Update 2018-003`, `Command line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode`, and `Safari` in App Store. App Store shows new versions available, that's why I upgraded them. These three softwares are what actually installed. I can't remember what it's called before the upgrade. The upgrade item was something like `Software tools`. After the upgrade, check app store update/installed history. The three software names shown.

Comment: @Buscar웃 FYI, I changed the region from China to United States. Login Screen and Shutdown popup window still show Chinese instead of English.

Comment: @Buscar웃 FYI, I have found the solution and posted as an answer. Simply execute `sudo languagesetup` in terminal and logout. Thanks a lot for your reply and time.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution. In terminal, execute the following command

```
sudo languagesetup
```

choose English in the command prompt and then logout and login again or reboot. The language in Login Screen will become English.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I had the exact same problem since half a year, login and shut down in simplified chinese, the rest in english. It's more of an esthetic problem but still.

Comment: Fantastic exactly what I needed 